# getting java.lang.ClassFormatError if i use SMTP code

Tags: java

I am trying to send a mail by SMTP from my code in java.
The problem occuring is quite unique and i am not sure if any of you guys have faced the same kind of issue.
I have already a bunch of existing code which runs fine without any error when i run if from Maven without the code for the SMTP in it.
But the moment i integrate the code to send mail by SMTP in it i start getting wierd exceptions and the jar file execution from Maven fails.
Below is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method     that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/Message
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

I searched the net also but could not get any proper solution as to why this wierd exception is occuring againa and again.
Can you please provide your comments on the sam as i have been stuck with this issue for a very long time now.

Comment: two possibility: (1) your class file for java is corrupted, or (2) you are using some bytecode transformation tools (aspectj ? profiling tools? bcel ? )

Comment: hi how do i know for sure that the class file is corrupted.why is that on only adding this SMTP code there is a issue and exceptions are occuring. i can run that file without any error after removing the SMTP code.

Comment: sorry, i means the java-mail (not java). Just download the java mail again.

Comment: Yes you were right here.May be this can help someone in the future. The main culprit is the javaee-api-6.0.jar.the SMTP code uses this jar.When you make entry for it in pom.xml maven downloads that jar from maven repository. But this jar in the maven repository has only declaration and not the actual implementation. so please dont add the entry and instaed make an entry for java-mail.jar in maven and your error will go. I dont know why Maven people are not adddressing this issue as it very misleading and we have to break our head on this issue .